# Python datetime format conversion

Tags: python, date

I am writing a small python program. Here I am getting date in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format (Time is in 24 hour format here **Example**: `2015-11-05 21:23:45`). I have to convert it to this format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM`

**Example**: `10/26/2015 4:00 AM`

I tried many date libraries but could not find any. May I know how to do this?

Comment: Can you share your latest code attempt at this?

Comment: Yea, show us what you tried. Seems like `datetime` is the obvious library.

Comment: *"I tried many date libraries but could not find any"* - how did you try them if you couldn't find them? There's one in the standard library!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I couldn't find library which does this. That's what I meant.

Comment: @sklearning given that there's one in the standard library that will do it, I find that really hard to believe - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: `strftime()` is what you are looking for. It's in the time and datetime modules

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
print(t)
```

Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to more time formatting codes that may help.